# Multiple Case Statements With Identical Expressions

Tags: t-sql, case, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to evaluate a specific column to return five different columns - but the columns are based off the same expression in the CASE statements.

```
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
     END AS [Invalid] ,
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 0
          ELSE 1
     END AS [validMICcode] ,
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 0
          ELSE 1
     END AS [validSerialNumber] ,
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 0
          ELSE 1
     END AS [validFormat] ,
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 0
          ELSE 1
     END AS [validProductionYear] ,
```

I feel like is causing the table / column in question to be searched for the pattern five times, but I cannot figure out how rewrite it - or if it is even possible - to have one pattern search and define the columns based on the one search.

I'm trying different variations, but I cannot come up with the correct syntax for this issue:

```
CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' THEN 1
          ELSE 0          
            CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 END AS [Invalid]
            CASE WHEN 0 THEN 0 END AS [validMICode]
            CASE WHEN 0 THEN 0 END AS AS [validSerialNumber]
            CASE WHEN 0 THEN 0 END AS AS [validFormat]
            CASE WHEN 0 THEN 0 END AS AS [validProductionYear]
    END
```

Comment: this work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a CTE..

```
with cte as(
select *,
CASE 
   WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0  
END as SomeColumn)

select *,
            CASE WHEN SomeColumn = 1 THEN 1 END AS [Invalid]
            CASE WHEN SomeColumn = 0 THEN 0 END AS [validMICode]
            ...
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be a sub query and Bitwise NOT.

```
select
    result Invalid,
    ~result validMICcode,
    ~result validSerialNumber,
    ~result validFormat,
    ~result validProductionYear
from
(

   select 
     CASE WHEN va.HIN LIKE '%[-=!@#$%^&*()<>?:|\;./,]%' 
       THEN CAST(1 As bit) 
       ELSE CAST(0 As bit) 
     End result 
   from ...
) tbl
```